# HTTP 500 when attempting to update Java application on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am unable to update App Engine Java applications (tried two applications), getting the following:

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck?runtime=java&release=1.9.5&timestamp=1400116984&api_versions=['1.0']
```

and then the update process hangs. I was able to update the same applications a few hours ago. Is there a bug or do I need to update something on my end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a known issue, but has since been fixed. If you have not already, I would recommend subscribing to emails from: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine-downtime-notify to get updates about system-wide problems.